# Difference between Python's 'img_as_ubyte' and Matlab's 'im2uint8'

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing, scikit-image

If I understand well the counterpart of Matlab's `im2uint8` in Python is `img_as_ubyte` from `scikit-image`

However the following gives difference results

```
Python 3.7:
--------
import skimage
from skimage.util import img_as_ubyte

img_as_ubyte([0.3]) # returns 76
print(skimage.__version__) # prints 0.16.2



Matlab (2017b):
--------
im2uint8([0.3]) % returns 77
```

In case it matters, this is under Windows 10

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what Matlab is doing, but scikit-image multiplies by 255 (the maximum value of uint8), then rounds, using [NumPy's default rounding](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.around.html#numpy.around), which is ["round to nearest, ties to even"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even). Here is a bit of experimentation that should clarify what is happening:

```py
In [10]: from skimage import util

In [11]: 0.3 * 255
Out[11]: 76.5

In [12]: np.round(76.5)
Out[12]: 76.0

In [13]: 77.5 / 255
Out[13]: 0.30392156862745096

In [14]: 0.30392156862745096 * 255
Out[14]: 77.5

In [15]: np.round(0.30392156862745096 * 255)
Out[15]: 78.0

In [16]: util.img_as_ubyte([0.30392156862745096])
Out[16]: array([78], dtype=uint8)
```